# Can I get a MAC address of another computer using an Ethernet cable?

Tags: ethernet

I am on a computer with Ubuntu 20.04
I would like to know if it’s possible to get the MAC address of another computer using an Ethernet cable. Both computers cannot access Internet, so the only connection between them is a cable.
Also I can’t use the IP address of the other computer.
Thanks !

Comment: maybe see https://superuser.com/questions/188799/how-to-find-the-mac-address-of-a-remote-computer

Comment: It doesn’t work. Only shows my IP address

Comment: Which command didn't work?

Comment: sudo arp-scan <ip_address_of_my_computer>. My IP address is manually set and is basically kind of a random one

Comment: if you know the ip address of the other computer but can't access it at all (via ping or anything) then you can't find out the mac address. To find out the mac address, both computers must be on the same network so that the arp table can be populated. Do you have just two computers and one ethernet cable with no router or hub? If so, plug it in between the two, then set two ip addresses on the same subnet in the network settings on both machines, and then use your arp-scan command

Comment: Well sadly I can’t access nor change the IP address of the second computer. My first question was not detailled enough sorry, but I can’t do anything on the second computer (aside from turning it on and plugging in an Ethernet cable).

Comment: so you don't even know the ip address of the second computer? If so, you're going to have a hard time finding the mac address. I think you're going to have to scan the entire network range looking for it. Do you even know what operating system it's running?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, but I thought it would work on any OS. To be honest, I wanted to try it on a Raspberry pi, as I don’t have any screen to check the MAC address. But atm the raspberry dosen’t have any OS

Comment: if you can plug a monitor into your raspberry pi you might be able to get the mac address via the bios